# Ubuntu auto updater crashed

Tags: unattended-upgrades

I was just running Ubuntu, and then I get a notification that auto-update crashed. (I don't like auto-update because I don't like things running without me knowing about it). Will my system be OK? (I closed the crash message before viewing the crash log) APT might be broken, though.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you running? Is it a desktop or server? Have you tried to to run the app **Software Updater**? Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1407830/edit) and add these information.

Comment: I am running version 20.04 Desktop. No, I have not tried running the app.

Comment: please run the commands `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`. Copy the errors (if any) and [paste them in your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1407830/edit). Then format the pasted output as `code` using the {_} icon above the edit window.